# cxGrid hide column

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe2, delphi-7

How do you hide/show cxGrid column in code ? I tried : `cxGrid2dbtableview1.Columns[mycolumnname].Visible  :=False;`
But it does not seem to apply.What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to identify the column by fieldname

```
var
 C:TcxGridDBColumn;
begin
 C := View.GetColumnByFieldName('cx1');
 if Assigned(C) then C.Visible := not C.Visible;    
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Columns collection is indexed by integer, not column name. Instead, try `cxGrid2dbtableview1.Columns[mycolumnname.index].Visible :=False;`

The other way is to set the column object's Visible property directly, `cxGrid1Column1.Visible := False;`

For columns created at run time, use Ken's answer.